# Reject repeated character in lex

Tags: regex, character, lex, flex-lexer

I need to write a regular expression for a flex program where it finds duplicate characters and rejects them, for example it approves of ABD but not ABDA or AABD because "A" is repeated in the expression. This has me banging my head for a week now, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I changed your tag to 'gnu-flex', because the 'flex' tag is used for the Apache Flex framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is in case insensitive:

```
.*(A.*A|B.*B|C.*C|D.*D|E.*E|F.*F|G.*G|H.*H|I.*I|J.*J|L.*L|M.*M|N.*N|O.*O|P.*P|Q.*Q|R.*R|S.*S|T.*T|U.*U|V.*V|X.*X|Y.*Y|W.*W|Z.*Z).*
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it doesn't work, it only finds continual characters ex. AAGD rejected but AGDA approved (which i dont want)

Comment: `.*(A.*A|B.*B|C.*C|D.*D|E.*E|F.*F|GG|HH|II|JJ|LL|MM|NN|OO|PP|QQ|RR|SS|TT|UU|VV|XX|YY|WW|ZZ).*`
Try put a `.*` between all letters.

Comment: Wow! It works! Thank you sooo much!! But, another problem occurred ( my mistake for not mentioning it ) how do I make it print a message if it approves of a word? To make it simpler I write [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ]+ printf("message"); and under that   .*(A.*A|B.*B|C.*C|D.*D|E.*E|F.*F|GG|HH|II|JJ|LL|MM|NN|OO|PP|QQ|RR|SS|TT|UU|VV|X‌​X|YY|WW|ZZ).* printf("message");   but it doesn't "see" the first rule of aprrovement :/

Comment: ok my bad, ignore my previous reply, I found it, I just changed the order of the expressions first the one of EdgardLeal and then mine. Again, thank you for your time. One last, thing though, can someone explain to me how the above code works? I am confused with all the * and the .

Comment: `.` indicate any character just one time, when used with `*` , the `*` indicate the character can appear many times or never.
`.*(A.*A).*` any thing many or never, letter A , any thing, many time or never, 
letter A again, and any thing many times or never again

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now! Again, you have help me a lot, I had reached my limit!!!

Answer (score -1):

match any character followed by the same match as in the brackets: `/(.)\1/`

**Edit:** this only matches continual letters. use `/(.).*\1/` for all matches.

Comment: ok, so I write something like this??? -->  /(.)\1/ printf("%s : rejected",yytext);

Comment: This is not valid syntax in flex or lex: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html